# Compiling Haxe targeting as3 using hxml, can't add path to subfolders

Tags: actionscript-3, haxe

i'm writing a game on Haxe targeting as3 flash palyer 11.1, and i've recently encountered a problem. I am using FlashDevelop as IDE and i can compile my game without any issues, but i wanted to add preloader. For that purpose i decided to use .hxml file that would merge precompiler and the game. However, when i use this construction:

-main Main
-cp src/com/variecs/ghosthouse
-swf bin/DeathIsImminent.swf

compiler fails to find the classes in the subfolders like src/com/variecs/ghosthouse/game,
src/com/variecs/ghosthouse/level etc. Adding these class paths as well doesn't solve the problem. Main class is located in ghosthouse folder, while all other classes are located in subfolders, and are then imported into main class if necessary. But if i add the classpath of the subfolders, compiler either fails to import them into Main.hx, or asks to write a full classpath instead of short version when declaring a variable. 
Is there a way of doing it right? How do I add the subfolders?

Note: build.hxml is located in root folder of the project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem fixed. I had to use -cp src instead and write a full classpath com.variecs.ghosthouse.Main, this fixes the problem.